# useEffect is running when any function is running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

First of all, I researched the question a lot, but I could not find a solution. I would appreciate if you help.

functional component

I add the code briefly below. this is not full code

state and props

```
  // blog id
  const { id } = props.match.params;

  // state
  const initialState = {
    title: "",
    category: "",
    admin_id: "",
    status: false
  };

  const [form, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const [adminList, setAdminList] = useState([]);
  const [articleText, setArticleText] = useState([]);
  const [me, setMe] = useState([]);
  const [locked, setLocked] = useState(true);
  const timerRef = useRef(null);

// queries and mutations 

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_BLOG, {
    variables: { id }
  });

  const { data: data_admin, loading: loading_admin } = useQuery(GET_ADMINS);

  const [editBlog, { loading: loadingUpdate }] = useMutation(
    UPDATE_BLOG
  );
  const [lockedBlog] = useMutation(LOCKED_BLOG);
```

multiple useEffect and functions

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && data) {
      setState({
        title: data.blog.title,
        category: data.blog.category,
        admin_id: data.blog.admin.id,
        status: data.blog.status
      });
      setArticleText({
        text: data.blog.text
      });
    }
    console.log(data);
  }, [loading, data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading_admin && data_admin) {
      const me = data_admin.admins.filter(
        x => x.id === props.session.activeAdmin.id
      );
      setAdminList(data_admin);
      setMe(me[0]);
    }
  }, [data_admin, loading_admin]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { id } = props.match.params;
    lockedBlog({
      variables: {
        id,
        locked: locked
      }
    }).then(async ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    return () => {
      lockedBlog({
        variables: {
          id,
          locked: false
        }
      }).then(async ({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    };
  }, [locked]);

  // if loading data
  if (loading || loading_admin)
    return (
      <div>
        <CircularProgress className="loadingbutton" />
      </div>
    );

  if (error) return <div>Error.</div>;

  // update onChange form
  const updateField = e => {
    setState({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  // editor update
  const onChangeEditor = text => {
    const currentText = articleText.text;
    const newText = JSON.stringify(text);
    if (currentText !== newText) {
      // Content has changed
      if (timerRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      }
      setArticleText({ text: newText });
      if (!formValidate()) {
        timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
          onSubmitAuto();
        }, 10000);
      }
    }
  };

  // auto save
  const onSubmitAuto = () => {
    if (timerRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    }
    editBlog({
      variables: {
        id,
        admin_id,
        title,
        text: articleText.text,
        category,
        status
      }
    }).then(async ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };

  // validate

  const formValidate = () => {
    const { title, category } = form;
    return !title || !articleText.text || !category;
  };

  // clear state
  const resetState = () => {
    setState({ ...initialState });
  };

  return (
    // jsx
  )
```

first issue, when call `onSubmitAuto`,  first useEffect is running again. i dont want this.
because I just want it to work on the first mount.

second issue, if the `articleText` state has changed before, when mutation it does not mutate the data in the form state. but if the form state changes first, it mutated all the data. I think this issue is the same as the first issue.

I hope I could explain the problem. :/

Comment: First of all, when you call **onSubmitAuto** it runs again the last useEffect beacuse the useEffect has *[locked]* and you chage the state of *locked* in **onSubmitAuto** everytime it changes the state of *locked* will run the last useEffect you have

Comment: I have no problem with locked, I removed locked from onSubmitAuto. the same problem continues. I updated the code. The problem is with onSubmitAuto and the first useEffect. @FernandoRamirez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, I have an answer to the first issue: when `onSubmitAuto` is triggered, it calls `editBlog` that changes `loading`. And `loading` is on first `useEffect` deps list.
If you don't want that, a fix could be something like that:

```
const isInitialMount = useRef(true);
//first useEffect
useEffect(() => {
if(isInitialMount.current) {
if (!loading && data) {
  setState({
    title: data.blog.title,
    category: data.blog.category,
    admin_id: data.blog.admin.id,
    status: data.blog.status
  });
  setArticleText({
    text: data.blog.text
  });
}
console.log(data);
if (data !== undefined) isInitialMount.current = false;
}
}, [loading, data]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but now setState does not work on the first load, so useEffect didn't work right now.

Comment: when i test this code  'console.log(data)' return undefined.  @Giovanni Esposito

Comment: Ciao, if worked before my suggestion, should work also after. What I have done it’s just use a bool ref to execute code inside useEffect one time. It’s strange... anyway if data is null if(!loading && data) returns false and setState will be not executed.

Comment: the old code also comes undefined 1 time in the console and then the data comes. How can we make the useQuery data async?  I don't know this right but,  useEffect is trying to get data  as soon as it mount.

Comment: old code loads the data correctly. but as I said it gives once undefined.

Comment: Ok, so that means that first useEffect on old code was being triggered more than 1 time correct?

Comment: yes correct, when load page 1 or 2 times undefined data comes after that.

Comment: Ok understood, so my suggestion it doesn't work because it allows you to enter in useEffect code just first time. I can made an update to "lock" useEffect only after data are valid. I will update in a minute.

Comment: Ok, as you can see with if(data !== undefined) I set isInitialMount.current to false only when data are valid. Could work.

Comment: When onChangeEditor changes, onSubmitAuto is running....  but first, after typing in the text editor, then change the title, it doesn't save the title or category.  but when I change the title first  or category and then update the text editor, it saves all the data. i think state problem

Comment: Oh ok, for what I see you call `onSubmitAuto` only from `onChangeEditor`. But you are also setting `articleText` on `onChangeEditor`. That could be an issue. With Hooks you don't have a callback in `setArticleText ` to be sure that `articleText` has the last value. What you can do is pass new value directly to `onSubmitAuto` like `onSubmitAuto(newText)` and use newText in `editBlog`.